# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})$ is not

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> How can I show that the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ but that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})$ is not?

I am kind of lost with Galois Theory.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1-\sqrt{2}})$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86259/mathbbq-sqrt1-sqrt2-is-galois-over-mathbbq)

Comment: Why are you lost? What about it confuses you? These are helpful questions whose answers you should provide in your post to avoid your post looking like an attempt to outsource your homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimal polynomial for $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ is $x^4-2x-1$, and has the complex root $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{2}}$.  If the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})$ were a Galois extension, it would be the splitting field and thus contain this element.

As for $\alpha=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$, the minimal polynomial is $x^4-4x^2+2$ with roots $\pm\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}},\pm\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ (and so is a separable polynomial).  Since $\alpha^2-2=\sqrt{2}$, we know $\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, and so $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ as well.  This shows that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is the splitting field for the minimal polynomial of $x$, so it is a separable extension, and hence Galois.