# Galois group of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{4+\sqrt 7})/\mathbb Q$

Tags: galois-theory

Let $\alpha =\sqrt{4+\sqrt 7}$ and $\beta =\sqrt{4-\sqrt 7 }$. I have to compute $Gal(\mathbb Q(\alpha )/\mathbb Q)$. So, I found that $Gal(\mathbb Q(\alpha )/\mathbb Q)=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, that $\mathbb Q(\beta^2)= \mathbb Q(\alpha^2)$. I show that the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha $ are $\{\alpha ,-\alpha ,\beta ,-\beta \}$. But now that ask me to enumerate the element of the galois group. I did it's $\{id, \sigma ,\tau,\sigma \tau\}$ where

\begin{align*}
\sigma : \alpha &\longmapsto -\alpha \\
\beta &\longmapsto -\beta 
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\tau : \alpha &\longmapsto \beta  \\
\beta &\longmapsto \alpha 
\end{align*}

But in my correction they wrote

\begin{align*}
\sigma : \alpha &\longmapsto -\alpha \\
\beta &\longmapsto \beta 
\end{align*}

**Question : Who is right ? me or the correction ?**

The problem it's that this group is abelian, so if they are right, $$\sigma \tau(\alpha )=\beta \neq -\beta =\tau\sigma (\alpha )$$
so I think I'm right, but in the doubt I prefer to ask you.

Comment: Shouldn't the second $\sigma$ be $\tau$?

Comment: Do you want the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ (is this Galois?), or of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$?

Comment: Since the extension is Galois and $\alpha $ and $\beta $ are conjuguate, $\mathbb Q(\alpha )=\mathbb Q(\alpha ,\beta )$ @MartinBrandenburg

Comment: And why is it Galois?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367383

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that
$$\alpha\beta =\sqrt{(4+\sqrt{7})(4-\sqrt{7})}=\sqrt{16-7}=3,$$
so $\beta=\frac{3}{\alpha}$. As a consequence, any homomorphism $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(\alpha)=-\alpha$ is also such that$$\varphi(\beta)=\varphi\left(\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)=\frac{3}{\varphi(\alpha)}=\frac{3}{-\alpha}=-\beta.$$
So the error is in your correction. Your answer is right.